Unable to start appium session
This is my first post,  please be patient if i made any mistakes.
I am trying to automate an android app called "Ifs Scan It" from google store. but appium cannot start the app.
the desired capability is set as follows:
{ "appium:automationName": "uiautomator2", "appium:platformName": "Android", "appium:platformVersion": "13", "appium:deviceName": "emulator-5554", "appium:appPackage": "com.ifs.cloud.ScanIt", "appium:appActivity": "crc64089f5dbede512c6e.Login" }
After starting appium server I can create a session with any other app that is downloaded in the emulator, but just not this one. that makes me believe there is no issue with appium server settings.
however, When i try to start "Ifs Scan It" app, it fails with following error:

Error
Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.ifs.cloud.ScanIt' application. Consider checking the driver's troubleshooting documentation. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'c:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am start -W -n com.ifs.cloud.ScanIt/crc64089f5dbede512c6e.Login -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000' exited with code 255'; Command output: Exception occurred while executing 'start': java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.ifs.cloud.ScanIt/crc64089f5dbede512c6e.Login } from null (pid=5500, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10159 at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPermission(ActivityTaskSupervisor.java:1110) at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.executeRequest(ActivityStarter.java:1024) at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:713) at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAndWait(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1562) at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAndWait(ActivityManagerService.java:3148) at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.runStartActivity(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:598) at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.onCommand(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:208) at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97) at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38) at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onShellCommand(ActivityManagerService.java:9197) at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:1049) at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:877) at...

copilot suggests: "This might be happening because the appActivity specified in the AppiumOptions, crc64089f5dbede512c6e.Login, is either not declared in the AndroidManifest.xml of the app com.ifs.cloud.ScanIt or it is declared but not marked as exported"
i dont have any access to development code, neither can contact the developer. Is there any other way I can make it work?
i tried to see if i can get access to AndroidManifest.xml app to modify it, but couldnt get access
I have tried getting the .apk file and tried to start the app using the apk file, that failed too
